# What is $\lim_{x\to 7^-} \frac{\left|x-7\right|}{x-7}\,$?

Tags: calculus, limits, absolute-value

$\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 7^-} \frac{\left|x-7\right|}{x-7} = $

Writing absolute value as:

$x-7 > 0$

$x > 7$

which means

$x - 7$ when $x > 7$

then:

$ -(x - 7) < 0$

$-x + 7 < 0$

$-x < - 7$

$x > 7$

which means

$-x + 7 $ when $x > 7$

So when $x > 7$ what equation should I use?

$x - 7$

or

$-x + 7 $

Comment: "$x$ approaches $7$ from the negative side": so we have $x\le 7$.

Comment: so what? I shouldn't care about it until I have separated absolute values. And then I simply look from which side my x approaches.

Comment: The first line after your then should read $-(x-7) > 0$, which is the other possibility for the absolute value, so you'll get the other case ($x < 7$) at the end. Is this what confused you?

Comment: But why > $0$???? I'm talking about when value inside the absolute value is negative, and that can happen only when x is less than $0$.

Comment: The value inside the absolute value is negative when $x - 7 < 0$, which is equivalent to what I wrote above. This can happen if $x$ is positive however. If $x = 6$, $x - 7 = -1$.

Comment: I don't see why" x−7<0"

Comment: Your main problem seems to just be that you don't understand the definition of the absolute value function.  It is *defined* as $$|f(x)| = \begin{cases} f(x), & f(x)\ge 0 \\ -f(x), & f(x) \lt 0\end{cases}$$ In your case $f(x) = x-7$.

Comment: @Bye_World I agree with you. :( To OP: what is your understanding of $|x|$ exactly? Can you define this?

Comment: It seems that you have misunderstood "$x\to 7^-$".  This means exactly that $x$ takes on values such that $x\lt7$.  This is why we have $x-7\lt0$.

Comment: @Bye_World per your definition. x - 7 ≥ 0 and -(x-7) < 0, right? Solving for both of them: x - 7 when x ≥ 7, and -x +7 when x > 7. Do you see the contradiction now?

Comment: @MagicMan well what Bye_World wrote.

Comment: You're confusing the *output* of the function with the *conditions* for which it applies.  $\color{blue}{|x-7|=x-7}$ **when** $x-7\ge 0 \implies \color{blue}{x\ge 7}$ and $\color{red}{|x-7| = -(x-7)}$ **when** $x-7\lt 0 \implies \color{red}{x\lt 7}$.

Comment: Why is it defined this way?  Because $x-7\ge 0$ when $x\ge 7$ and $-(x-7)\ge 0$ when $x\lt 7$ and that's good because the *output* of the absolute value function should *always be nonnegative*.

Comment: My sole reason for answering was to give you an actual picture to add some clarity, but this is a bit beyond me now. Hopefully what Bye_World has written will make it clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$|x-7| = \begin{cases} x-7, & x\ge 7 \\ -(x-7), & x\lt 7\end{cases}$$

Your limit is from the left side (I can tell because you've written $x\to 7^-$), meaning that you only care what this limit approaches for values of $x\lt 7$.  And in this region of the domain of your function $|x-7| = -(x-7)$.  So

$$\lim_{x\to 7^-} \dfrac {|x-7|}{x-7} = \lim_{x\to 7^-} \dfrac {-(x-7)}{x-7} = \lim_{x\to 7^-} -1 = -1$$

Comment: I don't see how you know that x-7 when x>= 7 and -x+7 is when x<7 why not the opposite?

Comment: @dramadeur That's the definition of the absolute value function.  Just remember, the absolute value function maps real numbers to nonnegative real numbers.  If $x\lt 7$, would $-(x-7)$ be positive or negative? (If you can't tell then plug in a value of $x$ that's less than $7$, like maybe $6$, and test it)

Comment: why do you immediately say x < 7 ???? How do you know it should be 7. Yeah right "that's where" function is $0$. So what, what if you have a polynomial and the function would never be zero? like |$x^2 + x$|?

Comment: How about at $x=-1$?  But ok, here's a better function $f(x) = x^2 +1$.  That function certainly never equals zero.  So if we took the absolute value of that function, we'd get $|x^2+1| = \begin{cases} x^2 + 1, & x^2 + 1 \ge 0 \\ -(x^2+1), & x^2 + 1\lt 0\end{cases}$, but because the condition $x^2+1\lt 0$ *never holds*, we'd always have $|x^2+1| = x^2+1$.

Comment: @dramadeur Maybe you're not understanding the notation, $|f(x)| = \begin{cases} f(x), & f(x)\ge 0 \\ -f(x), & f(x) \lt 0\end{cases}$.  What it means is that $|f(x)|$ is defined to be $f(x)$ (the output) *only when* $f(x) \ge 0$ (the condition).  Likewise, $|f(x)|$ is defined to be $-f(x)$ (output) *when* $f(x) \lt 0$ (condition).

Comment: @dramadeur (in response to your deleted comment) As $x\to 7^-$, the signs of the numerator and denominator of $\dfrac {|x-7|}{x-7}$ are $+$ and $-$ respectively.  So the answer must be negative.  As $x\to 7^+$, the signs of the numerator and denominator are $+$ and $+$ respectively.  So the answer must be positive.  I proved above that in the $x\to 7^-$ case, the answer is $-1$, and you can see from MagicMan's plot that in the $x\to 7^+$ case it's $1$.  If you still don't understand, get some sleep and read through all of these answers and comments tomorrow.  Maybe it'll click.

Answer (score 3):

The limit from the left means that $x<7$, that is, $x-7<0$, that is, $|x-7|=-(x-7)$.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps a graph would help here before trying to "prove" anything. For $f(x)=\frac{|x-7|}{x-7}$, we have the following graph for a sample viewing window:

[image]

As you can see from the graph of $f(x)$, when $x$ approaches $7$ from the right (i.e, $x\to7^+$), we have that $f(x)=1$; on the other hand, when $x$ approaches $7$ from the left (i.e., $x\to7^-$), we have that $f(x)=-1$. Dissecting what $f(x)=\frac{|x-7|}{x-7}$ actually *means* will make it easy to evaluate your limit. As Bye_World pointed out, 
$$
|x-7| = \begin{cases} x-7, & x\ge 7 \\ -(x-7), & x\lt 7\end{cases}.
$$
Hence, we have the following:
$$
\lim_{x\to 7^+}f(x) = \lim_{x\to 7^+}\frac{|x-7|}{x-7}=\lim_{x\to 7^+}\frac{x-7}{x-7}=1,
$$
and
$$
\lim_{x\to 7^-}f(x) = \lim_{x\to 7^-}\frac{|x-7|}{x-7}=\lim_{x\to 7^-}\frac{-(x-7)}{x-7}=-1.
$$
The figure above confirms this. Also note that $\lim_{x\to 7}f(x)$ does not exist since $\lim_{x\to 7^+}f(x)=1\neq-1=\lim_{x\to7^-}f(x)$.

Comment: I don't see why you'd assume x - 7 when x >= 7

Comment: @dramadeur Because $x-7$ is **not** negative when $x\geq 7$.

Comment: and you know that because ...? Why can't you say x - 7 is not negative when x < 7?

Comment: and even if it's true, then for the second ... thing, -x + 7 < 0, no? Then -x +7 when x > 7

Comment: @dramadeur Just try plugging in a value of $x$ that's less than $7$.  For instance $6$ is less than $7$.  So let's try that: $x-7=(6)-7 =-1 \lt 0$, so $x-7$ **is** negative when $x\lt 7$.  So that's **not** what we want.